# \inputencoding{latin1} cannot be used in the user documentation of a .dtx file if it is \DocInput

Tags: input-encodings, documentation, dtx, docstrip

**Third edit:** (As pointed out by Ulrike, my problem in fact doesn't concern `listingsutf8` but only `inputenc`, so I reflect this by giving to the question another title and another MWE.)

The following MWE points out that as soon as, in a `.dtx` file, both:

- the `ltxdoc` document `\DocInput`s the `.dtx` file itself,
- the user documentation (that is, the commented section) selects `latin1` encoding with `\inputencoding{latin1}`,

a strange error:

```
***************************
* Character table correct *
***************************
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin1.def

! Package doc Error: Character table corrupted.

See the doc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.53 %%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}

?
```

is thrown during a `pdfLaTeX` compilation.

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\inputencoding{latin1}
Foo bar.
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \inputencoding{latin1}
%
% \Finale
\endinput
```

I wonder what's going on.

Note that this strange error doesn't occur if:

1. either `\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}` is removed,
2. or the `\inputencoding{latin1}` declaration is directly inserted in the `ltxdoc` document body and not in the user documentation.

**Original edit:** The following MWE points out that as soon as, in a `.dtx` file, both:

- the `ltxdoc` document:

  - loads the `listingsutf8` package,
  - `\DocInput`s the `.dtx` file itself,
- the user documentation contains a `lstlisting` environment:

  - with the `listingsutf8`'s `inputencoding=utf8/latin1` option,
  - containing `utf8` encoded characters,

a strange error:

```
***************************
* Character table correct *
***************************
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin1.def

! Package doc Error: Character table corrupted.

See the doc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.53 %%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}

?
```

is thrown during a `pdfLaTeX` compilation.

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\begin{lstlisting}
ü
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \begin{lstlisting}[inputencoding=utf8/latin1]
% ü
% \end{lstlisting}
%
% \Finale
\endinput
```

I wonder what's going on.

Note that this strange error doesn't occur if:

1. 1. either `\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}` is removed,
   2. or `inputencoding=utf8/latin1` option of `lstlisting` environment is removed (in this case, a normal `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char` occurs),
2. the `lstlisting` with `inputencoding=utf8/latin1` option and containing `utf8` encoded characters is directly inserted in the `ltxdoc` document body,
3. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` are removed, `listingsutf8` is replaced by `listings`, and `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX` compilation are used.

**Second edit:** The same problem arises with a more conform use of `listingsutf8`:

```
% mylistings.txt file
\begin{lstlisting}
ü
\end{lstlisting}
```

and:

```
% .dtx file
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\lstinputlisting[inputencoding=utf8/latin1]{mylisting.txt}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \lstinputlisting[inputencoding=utf8/latin1]{mylisting.txt}
%
% \Finale
\endinput
```

Comment: Did you use the environment only for the example (`inputencoding=utf8/latin1` works only with the `\lstinputlisting`). The source of the error is imho that latin1.def is read in with `\endlinechar=-1` (or some other relevant change) and then the comparision of the character tables fails.

Comment: Indeed, I came from a more complex situation (involving `tcolorbox`'s `inputencoding=utf8/latin1` option) and forgot meanwhile `listingsutf8` claims "[o]nly `\lstinputlisting` is supported by the syntax extension of key inputencoding". But (1) a MWE with `\documentclass{article}`, `\usepackage{listingsutf8}` and a `lstlisting` environment with `inputencoding=utf8/latin1` option and containing `utf8` encoded characters works like a charm, (2) the same problem as described arises with `\lstinputlisting`. Do you think the bug should be reported to `inputenc` maintainers?

Comment: You can report it, but I don't know if it counts as bug and if something could be done. Btw: you can remove all the listings stuff, the error is triggered by `\inputencoding{latin1}` in the commented section.

Comment: I'll report the bug. You're right, the MWE can be made still more minimal :) and I'll edit my question in this respect.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I have made a LaTeX bug report with id `latex/4420` and also proposed the solution of my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233524/16967) for fixing the issue.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I didn't figure out it was a core LaTeX bug so I reported it directly to Frank Mittelbach (as `inputencoding` maintainer). But you're right: that's a better place for this bug to be reported.

Comment: Heiko reported this here, I guess we'll fix it before the 2015 release, thanks. http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/4420

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wrong character table comes from the wrong setting for `\endlinechar`, see Ulrike's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232791/inputencodinglatin1-cannot-be-used-in-the-user-documentation-of-a-dtx-file-i#comment551027_232791). The setting of `\endlinechar` to `-1` is done in `\inputencoding` to prevent additional spaces by line ends and `\par` tokens by empty lines, if `\inputencoding` is used in horizontal mode. Thus this setting of `\endlinechar` is necessary, not a bug.

Thus the question is rather, why is the character table in the comments is checked in the first place. `latin1.def` is not the argument of `\DocInput`.
The reason is the changed category code of the percent sign, which is active and not a comment character. Therefore `\inputencoding` can be made more robust, by ensuring the category code of the percent character.

Minimal example with applied fix:

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatother
\pretocmd\inputencoding{%
  \xdef\saved@percent@catcode{\the\catcode`\%}%
  \catcode`\%14\relax
}{}{%
  \errmessage{Cannot patch \string\inputencoding}%
}
\apptocmd\inputencoding{%
  \catcode`\%\saved@percent@catcode\relax
}{}{%
  \errmessage{Cannot patch \string\inputencoding}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% Hello\inputencoding{latin1} World
%
% \Finale
\endinput
```

If LaTeX3 category codes are in force (`\ExplSyntaxOn`, or implicitly by `\ProvidesExplPackage`, see [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232791/inputencodinglatin1-cannot-be-used-in-the-user-documentation-of-a-dtx-file-i/233524?noredirect=1#comment553134_233524)), they have to be disabled, because `\inputencoding` is not encoded by `expl3` macros:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequireExplPackage{...}
...
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pretocmd ...
\apptocmd ...
\ExplSyntaxOn
```

Other ways of patching:

```
\newcommand{\org@inputencoding}{} 
\let\org@inputencoding\inputencoding
\def\inputencoding#1{%
  \xdef\saved@percent@catcode{\the\catcode`\%}%
  \catcode`\%14\relax
  \org@inputencoding{#1}%
  \catcode`\%\saved@percent@catcode\relax
}
```

Or more elegant, package `inputenc` provides two hooks, that are called at the beginning and end of `\inputencoding`:

```
\inpenc@prehook=\expandafter{\the\inpenc@prehook
  \xdef\saved@percent@catcode{\the\catcode`\%}%
  \catcode`\%14\relax
}
\inpenc@posthook=\expandafter{\the\inpenc@posthook
  \catcode`\%\saved@percent@catcode\relax
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this patch doesn't work in case it is performed in a `LaTeX3` package, as pointed out by this [minimal example](http://gte.univ-littoral.fr/members/dbitouze/pub/latex/divers/inputencoding-made-more/downloadFile/file/test.dtx).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I have added two additional ways for patching, which both work with package `expl3`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé In an `expl3` package, the category codes are different, see updated answer.

Comment: That works, indeed :)

Comment: This issue has been fixed in the upcoming LaTeX release